# Django python - Module not found

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I am a newbie so I might have done something stupid. running python 3.3 and Django 1.6.2.

When I run the local server via command line, this is the error I receive "P/1.1 404 1712" and error on the browser is "module not found" and the exception location direct me urls.py line 22;

```
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

this is a part of urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import static



from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'signups.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is how my settings.py looks:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/whattheheck/static/'

# Template location
TEMPLATE_DIRS = {
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "whattheheck", "static", "templates"),

}

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/whattheheck/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "whattheheck", "static", "static-only")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "whattheheck", "static", "media")
    STATICFLIES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "whattheheck", "static", "static")

    )
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: where is the variable DEBUG at? Looks like its not being set so all of the stuff your trying to call is not being executed correctly.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Line 22 is `document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` and it is a part of urls.py code block:                                                        `if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: @NicholasYoung The debug is in settings.py;

`DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []`

Comment: Please provide the full traceback of the "Module not found" error.

Comment: Wait why are you trying to include file paths into urls? You shouldn't in the first place. Also im a bit tired BUT i do not think the if gets ran when your just trying to include a variable into a script. I could be wrong

Comment: @MaximeLorant 


It would not let me paste here as it is too long so I uploaded it on a link.

[link - Traceback](http://dpaste.com/393T6ED/)

Comment: @NicholasYoung sorry to keep you up perhaps if you get a chance you have a look at it tomorrow;

I am following an online tutorial which is doing this on python 2.7 but I want to do it on python3.3(I guess I like making things difficult for me). when I run the code on the machine through cmd I get P/1.1 404 1712 error.

(https://www.youtube.com/watchv=8t80DMAAps8&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzRgedo9IzmcpXYoSeDg29Tx&index=7)

has this changed in python3 compared to python 2.7

Comment: @MaximeLorant

Can you provide help on the following, it is sort of an extension of this error. No body seems to get it
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963325/python-django-page-not-found-error-404-static-error`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot one `static` in the import statement, [see the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development):

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
                    # ^^^^^^ this one
```

Right now, it tries to use the `static` module as a function but obviously, it does not work. The error `'module' object is not callable` is raised when you are trying to use a module object (for example `os`, `sys` or any third-party) as a callable (with a `__call__` method).

Comment: Oh duh, I completely passed over that xD

Comment: It still does not explain why I am getting a downvote (even it is not you) :(

Comment: I have no clue, it wasn't me. Stackoverflow scares me a bit with how much people want everything perfect.

Comment: @MaximeLorant Hey Maxine, It worked thanks... not sure who gave you a downvoter, sorry :(. It does not allow me give you a up vote because I do not have the minimum required reputation of 15 yet...but I sure will give an up vote as soon as I get the reputation. Thanks a ton x.

Another problem that I am facing now is that my css file is not loading up. If you would like I will create another question since you got voted down on this...let me know?

Comment: @MaximeLorant sure, will do. Thanks again.one thing I would like to clarify is that if the addition of .static is required in python 3x and not required in python 2x?

Comment: This import is from the `django` module and has nothing to do with Python 2/3. Unless this part of the Django code is changed, the import will always be this in every Python versions possible. Indeed, the modification of the language has no influence (and very few) on frameworks hierarchy.

Comment: @MaximeLorant Here you go, I have got enough reputation to up vote you now. Thanks for the help :)