# python django - page not found error (404)- static error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, python-3.3

I somehow got the application running on django (new to python and django) and although the page loads the default URL (127.0.0.1:8000) but it does load the css files. It produces following error css files are directly accessed.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
'css\bootstrap.min.css' could not be found
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Here is my settings.py page:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Template location
TEMPLATE_DIRS = {
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "whattheheck", "static", "templates"),

}

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "whattheheck", "static", "static-only")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "whattheheck", "static", "media")
    STATICFLIES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "whattheheck", "static", "static")

    )
```

and Here is the urls.py page:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static



from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'signups.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

can someone help with this please?

Comment: Where is `css/bootstrap.min.css` in your file system?

Comment: miss coma in `STATICFLIES_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "whattheheck", "static", "static"), <-- here )` f you really don`t have it - try to add

Comment: @HuuNguyen It is in the following location.

`C:\Python33\Scripts\whattheheck\static\static\css`

Comment: @zymud that didn't work:(

Comment: @HuuNguyen even if I try to change the url

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css`

to

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/whattheheck/static/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/static/css/bootstrap.min.css`

It still doesn't open :(

Answer (score 0):

After you add any kind of static files to your project you should execute

`python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: Okay, I changed the way i express myself

Comment: @Liarez  I have done that already, I guess that is why I am able to open the page on the browser but for some reason css is not loading.

Comment: Your `STATIC_ROOT` is getting the path to the static files good ? You can try to change your actual  STATIC_ROOT for something like `STATIC_ROOT=/var/www/path/to/static`

Comment: `Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/whattheheck/static/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
Using the URLconf defined in whattheheck.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$ [name='home']
^admin/
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, whattheheck/static/static/css/bootstrap.min.css, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.`